# What does this particular IF statement in C actually do (that also works)?

Tags: c, if-statement

I came across some sample code which works perfectly for my application, but I am not sure what is actually going on in the IF statement.

```
unsigned int steps;
uint16_t selected_steps; 

for (int j = 16; j>=0; j--)
{
    if (((selected_steps^(1 << step_number))>>j) & 0x1) {
          some code...
      } else {
          other code...
      }
```

I know the purpose of the code, it is to check if the bit at selected_steps[j] XOR step_number is 1 or 0. Selected_steps[j] is either 0 or 1. Step number takes values between 0-15.

But I don't understand what is actually done by doing

```
(1 << step_number)
```

and then what is done by doing

```
selected_steps^(1 << step_number)) >> j
```

I suppose that the above statement outputs a 1 or 0 since it checks against 0x1?

Comment: Please familiarize with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Comment: shift `1` to the left `step_number` times, xor with `selected_steps`, shift the result of that to the right `j` times, and then bitwise AND with `0x01` (also, `selected_steps` is uninitialized, so the results will change every time)

Comment: unexplicit way to check if bit is set

Comment: and if you don't know what is going on, how would you know that it _"works perfectly for my application"_

Comment: I know the basic of operators, like bit shift and ^ is XOR. Just not how they work when put together like above.

Comment: I didn't specify it in the question, but it is lighting up a row of LED's in a specific way.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding a complex expression, split it up into its smalest parts. Assign each small part to temporary variables, and then use the temporary variables to build up larger and larger expressions until you have the full expression. In your example you could have e.g. `unsigned int temp1 = 1 << step_number; unsigned int temp2 = selected_steps ^ temp1;` etc.

Comment: That is a good tip, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what happens if `step_number` differs from `j`. Then: `((selected_steps^(1 << step_number))>>j) & 0x1` does this:

- The XOR with `1 << step_number` changes some bit of `selected_steps` other than bit `j`. But, as we will see, we do not care about this.
- Then `>>j` moves bit `j` to position 0.
- Then `& 0x1` isolates that bit.
- The result is true iff bit `j` in `selected_steps` is true.

On the other hand, if `step_number` equals `j`, then the XOR changes bit `j`, and the result is true iff bit `j` in `selected_steps` is false.

So the expression is equivalent to `(step_number == j) != (selected_steps >> j & 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into steps.

```
uint16_t mask = 1 << step_number ; // A bit mask with single 
                                   // bit `step_number` set.

uint16_t xor_step = selected_steps ^ mask ; // Toggle bit `step_number`.

uint16_t bit_j = (xor_step >> j)  & 0x1 ;   // Get the single bit `j`

if( bit_j  ) ... // If bit j is not zero.
```

So for example when:

```
selected_steps == 0x5AA5 (binary:0101101010100101) 
j == 5
step_number == 10
```

then:

```
mask = 1 << 10 (Binary: 0000001000000000)

selected_steps: 0101101010100101
          mask: 0000001000000000
         -----------------------
           XOR: 0101100010100101 == xor_step
                      ^
                      |_ Toggled bit

                         ,- Bit 5 (j)
                         V      
     xor_step: 0101100010100101
shift right 5: >>>>>01011000101
                              ^
                              |_ Bit 5 moved to LSB

               0000001011000101         
        AND 1: 0000000000000001 == bit j
```

So you end up with bit `j` of `selected_steps` *after* bit `step_number` has been toggled.  If `j != step_number` then the toggling has no effect on the result.

How that achieves the purpose of your application is not possible to tell given the aggressive eliding of your code. Presumably in reality `selected_steps` and `step_number` are not loop-invariant (and `steps` not unused, and `selected_steps` actually initialised for that matter)?